# Nested macros in Racket

Tags: macros, nested, scheme, lisp, racket

I want to be able to write a nested expression like this:

```
(AND/OR expr1 op1 expr2 AND/OR expr3 op2 expr4 and so on)
```

Where AND/OR is essentially AND or OR. But I want to be able to write an infinite amount of them. I'm using the `define-syntax` to try to make this happen but I'm not sure how to accept infinite amounts of nested expressions.

Don't mind the expr's and op's in my example, that part I can handle myself. I only want to know how to accept infinite nesting.

Example:

```
(SELECT somecolumns
FROM sometable
WHERE something
AND/OR something
AND/OR (something AND/OR something)
AND/OR ...)
```

Comment: Do you have some sample inputs and sample expected outputs?

Comment: I edited the post with an example that might make things clearer.

Comment: It seems like you would benefit from writing your expressions like `(AND/OR expr1 op1 expr2 (AND/OR expr3 op2 ...))`. Then your macros will naturally compose. Otherwise you will be working against the s-expression syntax, which will make things difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Asumu says, in general it's simpler to deal with s-expressions, at least in order to ensure correct operator priority, but for some simple cases pattern matching of `syntax-rules` (and `syntax-parse` and co) makes this easy, using rest arguments and recursive matching:

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax parse-args
  (syntax-rules (AND) ; treat AND as a literal
    [(_)
     ; no more argument, return value:
     '()]

    [(_ (arg1 AND in-rst ...))
     ; Composed argument found, call parse-args recursively:
     (parse-args arg1 AND in-rst ...)]

    [(_ arg1 AND rst ...)
     ; AND operator found, parse left side and rest
     (list 'and
           ; parse the argument (may be composed or not):
           (parse-args arg1)
           ; then parse the rest of the arguments:
           (parse-args rst ...))]

    [(_ arg)
     ; in case the argument is not composed or does not contain AND, don't parse it
     arg]))

;; TESTS:
(parse-args 'a AND ('b AND 'bb) AND 'c AND 'f)
; -> '(and a (and (and b bb) (and c f)))

(parse-args 'a AND ('b AND 'bb))
; -> '(and a (and b bb))
```

However, note that the above code can become impractical when adding other operators.

**Edit:**
Together with the select macro:

```
(define-syntax SELECT
  (syntax-rules (FROM WHERE)
    [(_ select FROM from WHERE where ...)
     (list 'Select select 'From from 'Where (parse-args where ...))]))

; TEST:
(SELECT 'somecolumns
FROM 'sometable
WHERE 'something1
AND 'something2
AND ('something3 AND 'something4)
AND 'blop)
; -> 
#;'(Select
    somecolumns
    From
    sometable
    Where
    (and something1
         (and something2
              (and (and something3 something4) blop))))
```

Again, pattern-matching allows for cutting the list at the right point to get the rest arguments

Comment: I definitely see why this is a plausible way to go, but is it possible to combine this with the above statement syntax (SELECT FROM WHERE)? Sorry if I'm being a bit retarded here but racket is still confusing for me as I'm new to it.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add the SELECT macro, but if it's not clear to you then maybe it's not the best exercise to start with. I suspect you are not yet comfortable with recursion. If that's the case, you should probably avoid macros for now and keep learning about recursive functions and rest arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's just that I'm not comfortable with macros in Rackets yet, I'm very familiar with recursion from other functional languages. Again, thanks!